# SecKeyCreateWithData fails

Tags: ios, swift, rsa

I'm trying to communicate with my server via my iPhone. My server application is written in python and sends data encrypted with RSA. I tried using SwiftyRSA library, and have encountered an issue creating a PrivateKey. Whether I load data from .pem file or from `Data` it fails with

```
Swift.Unmanaged<__ObjC.CFError>(_value: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "RSA private key creation from data failed" UserInfo={NSDescription=RSA private key creation from data failed})
```

I then tried creating a SecKey myself using `SecKeyCreateWithData`, but it fails with the same error when trying to create a private key, public key succeeds, however. I tried it for multiple keys, all 4096-bit.

Tested on iOS 10 simulator. What could be causing this?

Here's a [set of keys](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA/files/769195/test_keys.zip) which show this behaviour. They were generated using python's Crypto library:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 
key = RSA.generate(4096)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample private key?

Comment: @Paulw11 included a test keypair which fails in swift but works in python

Comment: Please show the Python code you are using to generate your keys; I have tested with keys generated using openssl and with Cryptodome in Python and can't replicate the problem with your key